# Карта облаков реального времени

Tags: карты, веб-служба

Для 3D модели земли в реальном времени нужно получать карту облаков. Ранее тайлы облаков были свободно доступны на одном из серверов Google, но теперь их там нет. Также есть гугловская webgl Земля(не плагин Google Earth), там карта облаков в dds, и использование ее это совсем другая история.
Также нашел симпатичную на вид [карту](http://owm.io/modis), но там слои не отделены от от самой Земной поверхности и склеены неровно.
Исходя из этого есть несколько вопросов:

1. как получают такие карты?(в случае с [этим](http://owm.io/modis) это реальные снимки в течении суток)
2. есть ли в открытом доступе уже обработанные фото облаков с альфа каналом?
3. есть ли шанс более корректно "вырвать" их [отсюда](http://owm.io/modis)?

Comment: Для чего вам это? Просто интересно. По поводу неровной карты почитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: для 3D модели земли, чтобы добиться более реалистичного вида соответствуя реальным данным. По ссылке не нашлось полезного материала. Здесь не столько в проекции дело, сколько в том, как отделить слой облаков, хотя там есть разрывы, что представляют большую неприятность

Comment: Попробуйте задать этот вопрос на opendata.stackexchange.com